# Python: User input to generate a range

Tags: python

I'm trying to allow for a user to enter a number and for the output to generate a range based off that number. Below, is what I want a user to be able to enter, and what the output should be. What do I do to achieve the output?

input: Enter a number: 10

output: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

My end game is to construct a random password generator that allows a user to pick the amount of characters and from there how many need to be upper case, how many special characters, and how many numbers. I'm still learning, so if I'm not heading in the right direction please let me know without telling me how to do the password generator. Trying figure it out on my own. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have an actual question? You don't appear to have any code.

Comment: Hint: look up `raw_input` or `input` for 2.7 or 3.X respectively.

Answer (score 3):

In python 2:

```
n = int(raw_input('enter a number:'))
print range(1,n+1)
```

or in python 3:

```
n = int(input('enter a number:'))
print(list(range(1,n+1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you want to generate a range of numbers based off of the input. Python actually has a range() function, so if you want to ask for an input and then generate a range of numbers from 1 to that number, do the following:

```
output = range(1, int(input('Enter a number: '))+1)
print output
```

Note: If you are using Python 2.7, use raw_input instead of input

Comment: No worries. If it was the correct answer, please accept it :). Also, it would be helpful for you to edit your question to more clearly state what you need so that others might find it and be able to use the knowledge.